# (jquery) .clone().appendTo()

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I'm trying to clone an image then append the copy to the bottom of the image however it doesn't seem to work. When I append it in `"body"` it works but on the wrong spot.

```
$(".clone").on("click", function() {
      captainPlanet.clone().appendTo("captainPlanet");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming `captainPlanet` is your image, you can't append to an `img` element as they cannot have children. Instead, you could use [`insertAfter`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to insert the cloned image after the original:

```js
let captainPlanet = $('#captainPlanet');
$(".clone").on("click", function() {
  captainPlanet.clone().insertAfter(captainPlanet);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="captainPlanet" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
<button class="clone" type="button">Clone</button>
```